# How to update python 2.7 in HDP 2.2 using with Spark and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, ipython

I am trying to use Ipython and Spark in HDP 2.2 but it seems ipython is only supported from python 2.7.
I have installed Spark and tested well, but the after installing ipython using yum command the version of python is a problem.

```
[root@sandbox spark12]# ipython
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Ipython runs separately, but when I tried to use it with pyspark:

```
[root@sandbox spark12]# IPYTHON=1 ./bin/pyspark
IPython requires Python 2.7+; please install python2.7 or set PYSPARK_PYTHON
```

I like to know how to update python 2.6 to 2.7. It seems the system prevents me from uninstall python 2.6. My feeling is that Python is integrated with hadoop system and hard to separately update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late I know but I had a similar issue using CentOS.

I was able to resolve it relatively easily by downloading a Python 2.7 version of the Anaconda distribution

`wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-2.5.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

When that has downloaded

`bash Anaconda2-2.5.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

And following the instructions - choose a location to install anaconda and add this location to your path.

Once this is completed, type

`source ~/.bashrc`

You should then be able to run IPython with Pyspark

`[user@quickstart ~]$ IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
 [I 09:43:06.241 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user
 [I 09:43:06.241 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
 [I 09:43:06.241 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/`

Answer (score 3):

1. Python is not integrated with the Hadoop system.
2. Python 2.6.6 is the default version for Centos 6.5 / RHEL 6.
3. You should under no circumstances attempt to uninstall/update the default version, because it has system dependencies.
4. What you can do is to [install a newer](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/) version of python as alternative to the existing one.
   And launch IPython using the new version.